# Can Artificial Neural Networks Learn Language Models? Paper 2000 Implementation

Tags: nlp, neural-network, language-model

I am new to research field in NLP. I want to implement a paper [Can Artificial Neural Networks Learn Language Models?](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2405&context=compsci) In this paper first time a step was taken so that Neural Network can learn Language Model. I have understood the paper, everything is understandable just some confusions in last section of paper.

**I did not found any of its code.** Paper is too old (2000)  **I did not even find the Training data (Communicator Telephone Air Travel Information System) which was used at that time**.

I have also emailed about this to both professors of the paper but email id of one of them is expired and waiting for response from other one.

Can anyone help me in this situation? Your guidelines would be valuable for new comers in research field. I would be thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Really old doc according to NLP, but for me this doc looks like the beginning of new ERA of NLP which use black-box technics to learn a language model and seems like its further development turned in WORD EMBEDDING - as far as I remember the idea was presented in 2008 by Mikolov from google (google called its technic - word2vec). This is usage of recurent neural network to learn the model in the way words are presented as a vector of n-dimension(in google's word2vec it's n=128). This representation turned out to be very good as the similar word are closer to each other in space than other ones. Also arithmetic works there, so for instance: germany-capital+paris = france. 
Here you have nice article, explanation and also implementation in tensorflow according to word embeddings:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/word2vec/index.html
So there are some implementations already - as well as a ready corpus-data for learning own models.

**EDITED**

I corrected the link - was wrong one.
There is also word2vec implementation on google code in c++ but what is very useful in the google code project is a lot of additional dat. Here is the link:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/
There yo can find pre-trained models(1.5gb) and also links to train data:
Where to obtain the training data

> The quality of the word vectors increases significantly with amount of
>   the training data. For research purposes, you can consider using data
>   sets that are available on-line:
>
> - First billion characters from wikipedia (use the pre-processing perl
>     script from the bottom of Matt Mahoney's page)
> - Latest Wikipedia dump
>     Use the same script as above to obtain clean text. Should be more than
>     3 billion words.
> - WMT11 site: text data for several languages
>     (duplicate sentences should be removed before training the models)
> - Dataset from "One Billion Word Language Modeling Benchmark" Almost 1B
>     words, already pre-processed text.
> - UMBC webbase corpus Around 3
>     billion words, more info here. Needs further processing (mainly
>     tokenization). 
>     -Text data from more languages can be obtained at
>     statmt.org and in the Polyglot project.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This link is using data set of MNIST. Can you share some example which uses some real NLP data? That would be more relative.

Comment: Oh sorry I put wrong link. I edited it. This is the proper one:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/word2vec/index.html

Comment: I edited answer - adding a few more useful things what you might find interesting.